# Sort root aggregations (names) in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

How to sort aggregations by root names of aggregates? It seems ES is not keeping query order of defined aggregates.

```
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      ....
    },
    "agg2": {
      ...
    },
    "agg3": {
      ...
    }
```

In results I got:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "agg2": {
      ....
    },
    "agg3": {
      ...
    },
    "agg1": {
      ...
    }
```

All topics on SO are related on sorting/ordering within the aggregate (bukets) not the root list of aggregates also official documentation is missing this part.